# Lock real iphone volume in-app

Tags: iphone, volume

I have an alarm app in the appStore and want to set it up so that the user can NOT lower the volume(using side buttons) while the alarm is sounding. I cant find how to do this in the documentation, did I miss something?

Alarm Clock Free(the popular green one) by iHandySoft Inc. does it so it's possible. If you lower both the master & ringer volume to 0 and set the iphone on silent the alarm will still play full blast. Then you will find that your master volume has been raised back up to like 80%.

I am currently using AV Audio.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: OK, I just figured this one out.I'll jot it down.

I created a loop and used MPMusicPlayerController to return the volume to full every 10th of a second. Code:

Loop function:

-(void) OverideVolumeLevelLoop:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0f];
}

Then just NSTimer to loop this function:


    NSTimer *overideVolumeLoop = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(OverideVolumeLevelLoop:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

& Dont forget to invalidate your loop when done:

[overideVolumeLoop invalidate];

Comment: Congrats if you figured this out Andres! :) Please place your own answer below and mark this question as Answered soon as it is possible, thanks.

Comment: thanks Madhumal:) I will post this as an answer and flag it as 'answered' in 8 hrs since my reputation does not allow me to post my own answer any sooner:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured this one out.

I created a loop and used MPMusicPlayerController to return the volume to full every 10th of a second.

Loop function:

```
-(void) OverideVolumeLevelLoop:(NSTimer *)timer 
{ 
    [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0f]; 
}
```

Then just NSTimer to loop this function:

```
NSTimer *overideVolumeLoop = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(OverideVolumeLevelLoop:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

(You can run the loop slower but the user will notice the volume being raised back up)

& Dont forget to invalidate your loop when done:

```
[overideVolumeLoop invalidate];
```

This is based on this Thread:

[Set device volume on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393124/set-device-volume-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AVAudioPlayer's volume function? i.e

```
//some method that gets called when you want to play a sound
- (void)play sound {

audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
[audioPlayer play];

}
```

Comment: Thanks Deesho, This actually just modifies volume relative to the global volume set on the iPhone. I found a work around and posted it as a comment, I'll be posting it as an answer in 8 hours when the system permits me to self answer.

Comment: Great. It's always best to workout the solution your self. Best of luck.